# Help with protection agains SQL-injection

Tags: sql, security, ms-access, asp-classic, ado

I need some help regarding SQL-injection. Ive been reading about it, but still don’t understand how to protect myself against it.

I have a simple Access database with a table (“course”) containing names and dates among other things. I then have a old ASP page with a search form. Below the search form I have a div (“schema”) that I want to populate with the search result through AJAX. Everything works fine, but is there something I need to do to protect me from an SQL-injection? Here is a simplified version of my code:

ASP Searchpage with AJAX and form (index.asp)

```
$("#search").keyup(function() {
 var varSearch; 
 varSearch = $("#search").attr("value").replace(/\s/g,"+");
$("#schema").load('ajax.asp?q=' + varSearch + ''); 
});

<input type="text" name="search" id="search" value="Search.." />
<div id=”schema”></div>
```

ASP resultpage (ajax.asp):

```
q = request.querystring("q")
SQL = "SELECT * FROM course WHERE startDate >= #" & Now & "# AND (courseName like '%" & q & "%');"
While Not dbRS.EOF
str courseName = dbRS("courseName ")
Respone.Write courseName
dbRS.MoveNext
Wend
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

#### Update:

Here is what I've got so far. This is the whole page. I cant see whats missing. Do I need to do something with the Access database, or is it working straight away?

```
<!--#include file="includes/adovbs.inc" -->
<%
q = request.querystring("q")

SQL = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE (cNamn Like '%?%');"

Set cn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
set comm = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
set parameter1 = CreateObject("ADODB.Parameter")

cn.Open ("db.mdb")
Set cn.ActiveConnection = cn

parameter1.Type=adVarChar 'for example
parameter1.Size=25 'for example
parameter1.Direction=adParamInput
parameter1.Value=q

comm.Parameters.Append parameter1
Set recordset  = comm.Execute 

recordset.Close
cn.Close
Set recordset= Nothing
Set comm = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
%>
```

The error I get right now is "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified" on the line "cn.Open ("db.mdb")". I've tried with "cn.Open server.mappath("db.mdb")" but the error I get then is "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name too long"

Comment: The way to protect yourself it to use **parametrized queries** - not try to parse out "dangerous" characters - you'll never get them all.....

Comment: Beware of little Bobby Tables. http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: With a Jet/ACE data store, you don't have to worry about little Bobby Tables, since Jet/ACE can't execute more than one SQL statement at a time.

Answer (score 1):

SQL injection occurs when you do what you have there: taking user input and directly putting it into a SQL command.  Someone with malicious intent could try and submit text that would append additional SQL statements to the one you are trying to run.

The first line of defense would be to try and parse for characters that would allow injection.  For example, someone adding a single quote ( ' )  would end your string in the SQL statement, and allow them to try and begin a new statement.  If you run your q variable through a parse function you can try and prevent that.  Replacing one single-quote with two single-quotes will pass the single-quote through as intended by the user, and prevent SQL injection from someone malicious.

Additionally, you are better served by using stored procedures and parameters if you can.

Comment: Thanks for the help. From your answer this is what I´ve figured out:

q = Replace(request.querystring("q"), "'", "''")

Is this enough to protect me from a SQL-injection?

Comment: That will help, but is just the start.  Stored procedures or parameterized queries like marc_s said are even better.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304352  If not, you should at least read more about SQL Injection so you know what to look for.

Comment: With Jet/ACE, SQL Injection is limited to poking about to generate errors to figure out the data structure, and to changing WHERE clauses. It is simply impossible to insert additional SQL statements (as you say in your 1st paragraph) because Jet/ACE cannot process multiple SQL statements at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The danger is in allowing the `q` variable to be processed by SQL as an instruction.
you can protect yourself by doing:

```
q = request.querystring("q")
SQL = "SELECT * FROM course WHERE startDate >= #?# AND (courseName like '%?%');"
ConnStr = "driver=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb);uid=;dbq=" & Server.MapPath ("db.mdb")    
Set cn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 

set comm = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
set parameter1 = CreateObject("ADODB.Parameter")
set parameter2 = CreateObject("ADODB.Parameter")

cn.Open ConnStr 
Set comm.ActiveConnection = cn
comm.CommandText = SQL

parameter1.Type=adVarChar 'for example
parameter1.Size=25 'for example
parameter1.Direction=adParamInput
parameter1.Value=value1

parameter2.Type=adVarChar 'for example
parameter2.Size=25 'for example
parameter2.Direction=adParamInput
parameter2.Value=value2

comm.Parameters.Append parameter1
comm.Parameters.Append parameter2
Set recordset  = comm.Execute 

...you ASP code here...

'when your done dont forget to clean up the resources
recorderset.Close
cn.Close
Set recordset= Nothing
Set comm = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
```

Also, if you know a parameter is going to be a number , or a date, checking that it is indeed so , is good protection too.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I will try it. Is it possible to keep the "Now" variable instead of using a parameter? It is used only to fetch all the courses from today and forward, or is this also open for a SQL-injection? (Im really new to this).

Comment: Hello again. I get a Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8' Object required: 'ADODB' on the "set parameter1 = CreateObject(ADODB.Parameter)" line. Any idea?

Comment: for the first query , Now is a system function so its safe to keep it as is, but i would suggest that you move it to a parameter, so that SQL server can optimize against your query. (it will recognize that its the same query with a different parameter.) as for the second question, its my fault, i forgot the quotes... i now corrected the code above.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help Menahem, I appreciate it a lot. I still cant get it to work though, I get "The connection cannot be used to perform this operation. It is either closed or invalid in this context." error. I've spent a few hours now on trying to solve the problem, but I'm not really sure of what im doing here.

What kind of db connection should I use? Since this is all new to me, I am kind of lost here.

Comment: You are most welcome. i have updated the code to create a connection (i thought you had one). if you choose to create the connection every time on the page like i show here, its important to close the connection properly (as shown) every time after you are done with it. although you can opt to create it once per session (in global.asa), and keep it in the session ,that was common practice in old ASP implementations. [here's](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200190) an MS article with another sample

Comment: Thanks again Menahem. But since I am totally new to this, I still cant get it to work. I Had a connection and a driver and so on before, and everything worked as it should, but now when i use your technique, I dont understand whats missing and stuff. I've been googleing all day, but nothing really explains exactly what I should do. Right now I think there is a driver missing. Could I ask you to show me a fully working example? Im totally lost here.

Comment: can you post some more of the code that works for you? ill try and make it work.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time, helping me with this. What Im saying is, that before i heard about SQL-injection, the asp-page worked perfect. But now when I try this Stored procedures thing, i cant get it to work, since I dont quite understand what Im doing. I will post my current code below, which I have simplified even more, for you to see whats missing. Thanks again..

Comment: OK, i see the error is opening the connection to the database. you said that the page worked before, so can you use the connection from the working version of the page ? (i can see in the original code you posted, that you are looping a recordset. so you must have a connection there).

Comment: Hi Menahem, sorry for my late answer, but I've been away for the weekend. I still dont got this to work. My former connection was this: ConnStr = "driver=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb);uid=;dbq=" & Server.MapPath("db.mdb")
Set dbConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
dbConn.Open ConnStr

How do I implement that connection in your code? its weird that I cant find one single working example of this technique anywhere on the web, even though this sql-injection seems to be such a big problem for everyone. Maybe im looking in the wrong places?

Comment: Hope you had a good time, i have updated the code to use the connection string you provided. i think you might need some more background on how to work with a database from a web application, maybe then the samples you saw will make more sense.

Comment: Now I get this error "Object doesn't support named arguments: 'cn.ActiveConnection'" is it possible that I need to change something in the webserver? This is a simple access-database and classic ASP, and its always been working for me before. But since the customer now wants a search function on the site (which uses a wildcard in the sql-string) , according to alot of websites, I have to protect the database from SQL-injection. Im so lost here, but I appreciate your efforts. Any other idea of what can be wrong?

Comment: Could it be that I use a MS Access database? I just read somewhere that Access does not support stored procedures.

Comment: i'm sorry sir, its my fault , the `cn.ActiveConnection` should be `comm.ActiveConnection`. when i updated the code today, i made a mistake. you are corrcet its very simple and should work just fine. since we are not using stored procedures, Access not supporting them is a not a problem for us.

Comment: Still no good. Now I get "Command text was not set for the command object" on the Set recordset  = comm.Execute. It feels like were geting close here ;-)

Comment: Yes , indeed. i added the `comm.CommandText = SQL ` right after setting the active connection.

Comment: YEAH!!! It finally worked. This has been a struggle, but thanks to you Menahem and your patience, it finally worked. Thanks alot. There is only one last tiny thing: the recordset is empty. Its like the "(courseName like '%?%')" questionmark does not catch the "parameter1.Value=q" value. If I remove "like '%?%'" from the SQL statement, all the names in the table show up fine. Any idea?

Comment: You are most welcome. yes, i think i know why this is, try to this: `AND (courseName LIKE '%' + ? + '%');"` instead of the 'like' statement you have now.

Comment: There it is! Everything works perfect now. I thank you from the bottom of my heart for helping me with this.